# How to use busy table from view side?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have crons what inserts data to odds table each 5 minutes, processes are always active and table is always busy.

Now from view side i use odds table, and when someone click on some match it returns odds for that match but page loading is 5-20 seconds for single match, while other page requests are normal speed, when i click to change days and get all matches for that days than is normal because it select data from baby table, but when i click on single match there is problem.

My question is can i somehow use busy table from view side without 5-20 seconds waiting or i need to increase ram server size, or maybe to copy all odds data to some copyodds table for example?

Comment: Can you please show us the table definition, the query used to retrieve data from the table, and the query used in your cron job to update the table. Is the table in MyISAM, InnoDB, or something else? How many rows in the table? How many rows are needed by the slow pageview? How many rows are updated by the cron job each time it runs?

Comment: Copying a table:  `INSERT INTO new SELECT ... FROM old;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use following trick for insertion:

1. Method-1

> ```
> INSERT INTO TABLE_A (A, B, C, D) VALUES
> (1,1,1,1),
> (2,2,2,2),
> (3,3,3,3),
> (4,4,4,4);
> ```

2. Method-2

   Use `INSERT DELAYED INTO` if stale read is not an issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is solution. I find that my historic table is also problem because she has 100 000 rows.

Comment: The multi-row `INSERT` is good for speeding up inserts.  But what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @RickJames : The batch insert may contain multiple inserts. So, inorder to decrease the duration of table lock, multi-row insert can be used.